# Java logical operators in return statements

Tags: java, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

So I'm working my way through some of the questions on codingbat.com to solidify some of the things I've learned so far, and es expected there's some questions where the provided answer is different than how I solved the problem. So for one question I used a style/format I saw in an answer for an earlier question and got it to work fine, but I just want some clarification on the logic.

Here is the question:

Given 2 int values, return true if they are both in the range 30..40 inclusive, or they are both in the range 40..50 inclusive.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean in3050(int a, int b) {
  boolean in3040 = (a >= 30 && a <= 40) && (b >= 30 && b <= 40);
  boolean in4050 = (a >= 40 && a <= 50) && (b >= 40 && b <= 50);

  return in3040 || in4050;
}
```

So this answer worked, however I would like an expplanation on the return statement and exactly how the OR operator works with the two boolean variables. Also how would the statement work if there was an AND operator or a NOT before one of the variables.

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that it's in a return statement is entirely irrelevant. It could be `boolean result = in3040 || in4050; return result;`. So, what research have you done about the `||` operator? Have you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html?

Comment: With AND it would return true when both a and b were 40. With a NOT one of the ranges would be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

In Java a logical term is evaluated from left to right. This means:

- for an OR-Statement: a || b --> if a is already true, then the whole term has to be true, b won't be evaluated, if a is false, b can still be true, in that case both variables would have been evaluated
- for an AND-Statement: a && b-> if a is already false, then same logic applies: the b variable doesn't need to be evaluated

You can imagine rewriting your conditional operation as follows:

```
if (in3040) {
 return true;
}
if (in4050) {
 return true;
}
```

Considering the case of using the &&-Operator it would look like

```
if (!in3040) {
 return false;
}
if(!in4050) {
 return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

These operators works exactly the same in the return statement as in every other place in the program.

Answer (score 1):

**Equivalency**

`return [some expression]` is equivalent to `return ([some expression])`

Thus, `return in3040 || in4050;`  is equivalent to  `return ( in3040 || in4050 );`

Comment: You are confusing statements and expressions.